# python add static string to all items in set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have the following set in python (its actually one set item):

```
  product_set = {'Product, Product_Source_System, Product_Number'}
```

I want to add a static prefix (`source.`) to all the comma seperated values in the set, so I get the following output:

```
 {'source.Product, source.Product_Source_System, source.Product_Number'}
```

I tried with a set comprehension, but it doesn't do the trick or I'm doing something wrong. It only prefixes the first value in the set.

```
{"source." + x for x in set}
```

I know sets are immutable. I don't need a new set, just output the new values.

Anyone that can help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](https://ideone.com/bRhjdz) The prefix is added to all elements, as expected. (Also don't call your sets `set` - it hides the `set` builtin.)

Comment: Ahhh my bad, it appears I have quite a weird set, with one big comma seperated value.  I've changed my starting post

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Splitting the initial long string into a list of short strings and then (only if required) making a set out of the list:

```
s1 = set('Product, Product_Source_System, Product_Number'.split(', '))
```

Constructing a new set:

```
s1 = {'Product', 'Product_Source_System', 'Product_Number'}
s2 = {"source." + x for x in s1}
```

Only printing the new strings:

```
for x in s1:
    print("source." + x)
```

Comment: Thx for the swift response, I've made a mistake in the starting post and I've edited it.

Comment: I've updated the initial response

Answer (score 2):

Note: The shown desired result is a new set with updated comma-seperated values. Further down you mentioned: *"I don't need a new set, just output the new values"*. Which one is it? Below an option to mimic your desired result:

```
import re

set =  {'Product, Product_Source_System, Product_Number'}
set = {re.sub(r'^|(,\s*)', r'\1source.', list(set)[0])}
# set = {'source.'+ list(set)[0].replace(', ', ', source.')}
print(set)
```

Prints:

```
{'source.Product, source.Product_Source_System, source.Product_Number'}
```

Comment: either works for me, but your solution returns an error unfortunately. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @JVGBI, please note the greyed out option without Regex.

Comment: Works like a flaw, thank you so much! :)